# How to animate several nodes with pause between each one?

Tags: animation, javafx

I am trying to animate a series of nodes one after the other in a loop. The goal is to have the first node begin its animation, followed by a short pause before the next node begins to animate.

However, when running this within a loop, it executes too fast and all nodes appear to be animating at the same time.

For simplicity, I am using the [AnimateFX](https://github.com/Typhon0/AnimateFX) library to handle the animations, but I assume the functionality needed here would apply in other situations?

How would I add a pause between each of the HBox animations?

```
import animatefx.animation.Bounce;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AnimationTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        final VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        final HBox tiles = new HBox(5);
        tiles.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // Create 5 tiles
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            HBox tile = new HBox();
            tile.setPrefSize(50, 50);
            tile.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black; -fx-background-color: lightblue");
            tiles.getChildren().add(tile);
        }

        Button button = new Button("Animate");
        button.setOnAction(event -> {

            // Animate each tile, one at a time
            for (Node child : tiles.getChildren()) {
                Bounce animation = new Bounce(child);
                animation.play();
            }
        });

        root.getChildren().add(tiles);
        root.getChildren().add(button);

        primaryStage.setWidth(500);
        primaryStage.setHeight(200);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know AnimateFX, but using the standard libraries you can add animations to a [`SequentialTransition`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/SequentialTransition.html).

For example, to animate each node but starting at a later time, add `PauseTransition`s of increasing duration and the desired animation to `SequentialTransition`s, and play the `SequentialTransition`s.

As I said, I'm not familiar with the library you're using, but I think it would look like this:

```
    Button button = new Button("Animate");
    button.setOnAction(event -> {

        Duration offset = Duration.millis(500);
        Duration start = new Duration();

        // Animate each tile, one at a time
        for (Node child : tiles.getChildren()) {
            Bounce bounce = new Bounce(child);
            PauseTransition delay = new PauseTransition(start);
            SequentialTransition animation = new SequentialTransition(delay, bounce.getTimeline());
            animation.play();
            start = start.add(offset);
        }
    });
```

Comment: This solution works, to an extent, however it requires waiting until the prior animation is completed before beginning the next one. Is it possible, for example, for the next HBox to begin its animation as the prior animation reaches its midpoint?

Comment: @Zephyr See update. To get exactly what you describe, set `offset` to half the duration of the bounce.

Comment: Perfect with the update. Thank you.